# 3 byte UTF-8 String replacement in .NET (Convert 3-byte UTF-8 to String or Char)

Tags: .net, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoding string I am getting from reading a PDF, and I am trying to strip out some characters that represent spaces but are not encoded as the standard 0x20 space. My problem is that the characters are represented by 3-bytes of UTF-8 and I can't figure out how to get that into a string or character so I can do a replace. The two UTF-8 characters I am trying to replace are 0xE28087 and 0xE28088.

I have tried Chr and ChrW which only take integer parameters up to 65,000 (presumably items that can be represented in a single byte in UTF-8)

I also tried using System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars() with the byte representation of my characters, but the result seems to be 4 chars instead of just one - IE it is interpreting my 3 byte character as separate one-byte characters

```
    Dim ResultChars() As Char
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim SpaceChar As Int32

    SpaceChar = Integer.Parse("E28087", Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(SpaceChar)
    ResultChars = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bytes)
    For Each ResultChar In ResultChars
        Debug.WriteLine(ResultChar)
    Next
```

What I am trying to do in pseudocode is simply:
ConvertedText = ConvertedText.Replace(StringOrCharofThisUnicodeCharacter("0xE28087"), " ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing code points with UTF-8 encoding. Internally, all .NET strings use UTF-16 so you just need to specify the Unicode code point, *not* UTF-8 byte data:

```
Const FigureSpaceChar As Char = ChrW(&H2007)
```

Codepoint from [www.fileformats.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm).

Comment: .NET uses UTF-16, not UTF-32. (Each char is a UTF-16 code point.)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much - For others reading the other space I am trying to replace is ChrW(&H2008) from that same site.